# How do I track and handle an event in node

Tags: node.js, events, event-handling

- So let's say I want to make a twitter bot. I want to send a certain message to whoever has sent it a reply, so I need to make an event for it. Obviously one way is to get all the replies (or last n replies) in a certain time interval, find out which ones are new, etc; but first of all it's not live, and it requires an extra query to find  new tweets.
- Say we want to track some changes in a website. For instance, we want to handle an event when that change happens, instantly.

I used `socket.io` to handle some other kind of events, like when some changes happen in a particular port, but I couldn't figure out how I can handle these types of events.

Comment: Is this question about how to know when some specific change occurs on Twitter?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not asking specifically about twitter, but yes that's somehow my first question

Comment: Well, if you want to get proactively notified of a change in some other web-site without polling it (e.g. reading it over and over every xx seconds), then you'll have to use an API from that web-site and any answer would be completely specific to that API.  So, I can't really tell what you're asking if you're not asking specifically about Twitter.

Comment: @jfriend00 so you mean I need to do something like `setInterval(get_replies, 10)` ?

Comment: If you're approach is to poll the site for changes, then you would use something like `setInterval()`, though not every 10ms like you show.  You may get rate limited (e.g. blocked by the site) if you're doing it too often.  Also, there are terms of service that may influence what you can and cannot do in this regard.

Comment: @jfriend00 alright, thanks. Any suggestion to distinguish new data from old one?

Comment: You have to keep track of the old data or some property of the old data that lets you distinguish it from new data.  What exactly you do there is again entirely dependent on the specific data.

Comment: Hooman, at this point I feel that this question is too broad.  There are many types of third party inputs you can write a server side script to handle -- you seem to be lumping all types into the word "event."  the reality is that every instance of information you want your code to be able to access must be accessed in a unique way.  Twitter will be via API, web site content will be via http.get.  The list will go on forever!

Answer (score 0):

The word "event" does not mean what you think it means!

- In a DOM environment, [an Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) is a very specific (and core) concept which allows you to write code based on user interactions with elements on the screen.
- In NodeJS, [an Event](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) is something that can be generated and announced by an instance of `events.EventEmitter`
- In your question, an Event seems to refer to anything that happens on the internet, potentially anywhere.

Under that last definition, there is simply no single answer for how to "track an event."

If you want to write code that can respond to change (which is just a more specific version of "react to an input") you need to create a mechanism to identify that a change has occurred, followed by a mechanism to trigger whatever code you want to be run in response (this last part is you would normally call "emitting" an "event").

SocketIO accomplishes both of these things for certain situations, using a graceful degredataion of protocols in order to explicitly emit local events that you can listen for and handle.  It starts trying to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets), and eventually falls back to more expensive techniques such as [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29).

SocketIO only works if the source of the information or change has decided to support the protocol.  In those cases, the source is actually emitting the event (over websockets) and socketIO listens for it.

In cases where the source of the information you are looking for does not support websockets (and hasn't been coded to explicitly notify your servers of changes), you are going to have to come up with your own solutions.  However: *You shouldn't think of this as a case of tracking "events".*  Rather, you are watching for changes.

How you watch for changes will depend on the nature of the change.  Generally you'll [probably have to poll](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Long%20Polling%20in%20NodeJS) for it.